# Collapsible Panel with only title visible when collapse to the side

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create Panel as a div with two divs (title and content) inside.
something like that:

```
<div class="left-panel">
    <div class="title">
        <span>title<span>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <span>some content</span>
    </div>    
</div>
```

I want to collapse this panel after clicking on arrow. After collapse it should be only a narrow bar on the left side, so the other panels next to it could be wider. it should be like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gQSk6.jpg
Something like that. I'm having problem with CSS that should be written to make it working. What should I do, to make it looking like that? I mean here only making content part to disappear and somehow rotating whole panel and title div with text to the left side.

Comment: What have you tried? Post your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript you'll toggle the class ('`collapsed`' or something like that) on parent element (`left-panel`). Then you'll have additional css rules for .`left-panel.collapsed`, something like this:

```
.left-panel.collapsed > .content {
    display: none;
}

.left-panel.collapsed {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

This is for basic rotation and hiding the content. You'll probably need some additional css for animation, sizes, position etc.

Comment: I think that's what I was looking for! :) I need to work on it a little bit more, as my custom components tend to position a little bit strange after doing it, but yeah, it looks good. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to Achieve the results...!!

REFERENCE: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sidenav.asp

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>   
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#toggle').click(function toggle(){
$("#sidebar").toggleClass("collapsed");
$("#content").toggleClass("col-sm-12 col-sm-9");
});
```

```css
.collapsed {
        display: none;
        margin-left: -25%; /* same width as sidebar */
    }
.btn{
  display: block !important;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="row-main">
        <div class="col-sm-3" id="sidebar">
            Your sidebar content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 pull-right" id="content">
               <button class="btn" id="toggle">Toggle</button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Put this code to the left side of the web page